Equation of motion of quantum fluctuations/ quasi particles
I have a question in my mind, that is haunting me for some time now. I am looking for an equation of motion for a quasiparticle. My actual problem is originated in the Gross-Pitaevski model and the inclusion of quasiparticle excitations at zero-temperature (quantum fluctuations), that are allowed due to the priciple of uncertanity of Heisenberg. This is well studied (e.g. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.155302). The interaction energy density of such a system reads then as
$$\frac{E}{V}=\frac{gn^2}{2}(1+\frac{128\sqrt{na^3}}{15\sqrt{\pi}})\,\, ,$$
where $n$ denotes the particle density and $g$ is an interaction strength and $a$ a scattering length. The first part is the mean field energy and the second part is the energy correction for quantum fluctuations/quasiparticles. The state of the condensed system is $\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)$, which is conndected to the particle density by $n=\Psi^*\Psi$. From the energy density we can derive the equation of motion by using a variational approach. The equation of motion is called Gross-Pitaevski equation and is equivalent to a Schrödinger-equation $\dot{\Psi}\propto \hat{H}\Psi$. My question is now how can an equation of motion for a quasiparticle look like. Is it also a Schrödinger-equation or any relativistic wavefunction (no idea why)? I am aware of the fact that it does not make any sense to calculate a trajectory of such an quasiparticle since it is an quantum fluctuation only. I also now that the lifetime of the quasiparticles is limited. Is that the point? We can not write down an equation of motion because the quasiparticles have a short lifetime?
I am interested in which equation of motion a quasiparticle follows and how we can derive that.

In the fractional quantum Hall effect, the relevant quasiparticles are composite fermions.  These have the same equations of motion as the regular electrons of the integer quantum Hall effect, which is of course the one given by the ordinary many-body Schrödinger eq.

Thank you for your answer @MariusLadegårdMeyer ,but i think the situation is different. In the quantum hall effect the composite fermions are excited states, right? In my question the quasiparticles are quantum fluctuations and no excited states. They are allowed due to Heisenbergs principle of uncertanity only. Maybe my question is unprecise. I will change the title.

They are not necessarily excited states, the ground states of the Jain sequence can be expressed in terms of CFs. But I agree that they are not based on fluctuations.

Err... what?  There is far less information contained in that expression of one-loop-approximate energy density compared with the full Hamiltonian.  There is no way to get Gross-Pitaevskii equation out of that energy.  And by definition the time evolution is given by the Schroedinger equation if you stick to standard, generally accepted quantum mechanics.
